# Can a switch be downstream?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

Whenever I go looking for diagrams, instructions, videos, or other guidance on  wiring electrical switches I always see the switch be upstream of the thing that's being switched on and off.

Is there a theoretical or practical reason to order the things on the circuit that way?

My first thought says that since a switch is basically just opening and closing the ends of the hot wire in a circuit that there's no reason the switch *couldn't* be downstream.

Is that normal, is it weird but ok, is it troublesome, or is it downright dangerous?

Comment: Please revise your question to clarify what "downstream" means. It's quite ambiguous. A specific example would be great.

Answer (score 6):

In the US/Canada (other countries may have things a little bit different) the normal residential configuration is:

- Two hot legs that are 240V from each other - that's used for hot water heaters, ovens, EV charging, etc.
- Neutral tapped in the middle, so each hot is 120V from neutral - that's used for lights, small and many large appliances, computers, etc.
- Ground is *bonded to neutral* and connected to ground rods and/or Ufer ground and/or metal water pipe to make it literally "ground"

That last one is the key. Because neutral and ground are connected together, if everything else is wired correctly (which is **not** always the case...) then if a person touches neutral, even while standing barefoot on a wet floor, they won't get zapped.

Because of that, the *hot* wire is always the wire that is switched. With simple wiring configuration, that means "upstream" and not "downstream". Think about a simple light bulb socket. If you turn off a switch on the *hot* wire and reach for a bulb to remove and it breaks and you touch things you shouldn't, you may end up with cuts from glass and metal. But you *won't* end up zapping yourself because at that point you have:

- Disconnected hot - it just isn't there
- Neutral
- Ground

and neutral and ground are at the same potential, so no electricity flows between them.

There are plenty of other scenarios possible, and plenty of other safeguards (if you are doing anything more than replace a bulb, turn off the breaker for safety, and if a bulb breaks, turn off the breaker for safety) but switching hot rather than neutral definitely makes things safer.

It *is* possible to switch hot while "downstream" using a *switch loop*. Switch loops are very common in older houses because they could save wire. With a switch loop you send hot and neutral to the light fixture, hot bypasses the light fixture and goes to the switch and comes back as switched hot to the light fixture. So you have a 2-wire (plus ground) cable everywhere and potentially save some cabling distance. But with current code each switch box generally requires neutral, which simple switches don't actually use, so you now need a 3-wire cable for a switch loop and it ends up costing more rather than less, generally speaking.

As a result, you don't see "downstream" switches as much in newer houses, and where you see them in older houses they *should* actually be switching hot, not neutral.

Comment: In the UK it's 1 Live wire (=hot), 1 neutral wire, 1 earth wire (=ground). The codes require the live to be the one that is switched. (This is just for info to anyone reading; this wasn't worth a separate answer as the rest of the text is basically still applicable.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking "can we switch the neutral instead of the hot"?  No, that's dangerous, and see what manassehkatz says. There's no benefit whatsoever to doing that, since the hot is *right there* and can simply be switched instead.  If you're thinking of some crazy routing where hot won't be alongside neutral, that's not allowed per NEC 300.3.

Are you asking "can the string from the power source to the lamp have the switch beyond the lamp, like this"?

```
  Power source ------ Lamp ===== Switch
```

Then yes, that absolutely can happen, but you'll need to use special cable between lamp and switch.  This arrangement is called a switch loop, and that's fine.

The trick is smart switches. They need neutral, so you need to bring neutral to the switch per NEC 2011 (to keep people from misusing ground for that).  So the cable from lamp to switch must be "/3" (black red white ground), with white as literal neutral, black as supply hot, and red as switched-hot.  Black and red can be swapped but it'll be more confusing if you do.